# Are we supposed to play both Pokemon Sun and Pokemon Moon or just one of them?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Is the Pokemon Sun and Moon the same as Pokemon X, Y, Sapphire and Ruby? (I haven't played those before). That, you are only supposed to play only one of X and Y, or play only one of Sapphire and Ruby?

I bought both Sun and Moon, and played 2 hours of Sun, and then put Moon into the same 3DS console, and played it for the first 30 minutes, and found that it is the same identical content and storyline. Even when we can choose one of 3 Pokemons as a friend, it is the same exact Pokemons. Is it only the later Pokemons that will be different? I really don't want to repeat the same storyline twice.

When I buy it from the game story or electronic store, their advice seemed to be "buy one, good, buy both, even better."

Comment: Because they do.

Comment: This is how all Pokémon games have worked. Each game has some version exclusives and the mascot is a different legendary. The most divergent story is in ruby and sapphire, but even then, only the details of the plot changed, but they followed the same course.

Comment: @Frank the most intelligent thing I have heard in the whole month

Comment: @Vemonus I think if a company releases two games and they are almost identical, it might be more ethical to let customers know you really need to only buy one.

Comment: @太極者無極而生 yeah I agree with you.

Comment: Literally every generation of Pokemon games have been this way, since Pokemon's debut initial release in 1996. I would think it was originally done that way to encourage friends to play different versions and trade the version exclusives between each other.

Comment: not everybody played Pokemon since 1996, you have to understand. Even today, I went into Best Buy, and they encouraged buying both versions of the game, "because you will get different Pokemons and unlockables", they said. I am not sure I'd agree with that after playing both. Maybe it is better to buy one and play that, and do some trading with your friends or as Trent suggested, to trade online

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Firstly, their job is to sell you as much stuff as they can. Secondly, they're absolutely right that both games have exclusive Pokémon and items. What they don't tell you is that 99% of the game is the same, and why would they? See point 1. Thirdly, I'm looking at the back of my Y and Alpha Sapphire boxes and they both state that the difference between versions is what Pokémon you can encounter and their frequency. Sorry to say, you just didn't do much research and bought something you ended up regretting.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer just because Best Buy is in the business of selling doesn't mean you should buy both. It says you will catch different Pokemons and get different items, but does it say the storyline is exactly or 99% the same? My question is: should we play both, and it is a valid question. My question is not about: is it wrong to sell both versions

Answer (score 5):

Just one. The differences between the two are largely cosmetic, and mostly determine which of the mascot legendary Pokemon you will encounter (the one on the box art) as well as a handful of pokemon in the regional/national pokedex that will only appear in [one of the games](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/exclusives.shtml), necessitating *some* trading in order to "catch 'em all".

Modern Pokemon games have made it less arduous to obtain Pokemon not found in your half of the version pair thanks to online connectivity. In the past, you *needed* a friend with the opposite version to collect them all (as well as at least one of you having a link cable to connect your systems).

So unless you have no friends willing/able to play pokemon, and limited (or no) ability to go online with your 3DS, there is little reason to buy *both* unless you intend one to be a gift for a friend. It is a marketing gimmick that has become one of Pokemon's trademarks, and more than a few other developers have attempted to mimic (Yokai Watch, Megaman Battle Network, Medabots, etc)